# Symfony 1.4: Second app on custom domain?

Tags: mod-rewrite, routes, symfony1, apache2, symfony-1.4

PHP start scripts:

- Primary app:

  ```
  ~ec2-user/project/web/index.php
  ```
- Secondary app:

  ```
  ~ec2-user/project/web/api1.php
  ```

Apache configuration:

- Excerpt from `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName example.com

      DocumentRoot /home/ec2-user/project/web
      DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
      <Directory /home/ec2-user/project/web>
          AllowOverride All
          Allow from All
      </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName 1.api.example.com # 1: version number

      DocumentRoot /home/ec2-user/project/web
      <Directory /home/ec2-user/project/web>
          AllowOverride None
      </Directory>

      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api1_dev.php [QSA,L]
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- `~ec2-user/project/web/.htaccess` (should only apply to primary app):

  ```
  Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
    # getting no_script_name to work
    #RewriteBase /

    # we skip all files with .something
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
    #RewriteRule .* - [L]

    # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
    RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
    RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
  </IfModule>
  ```

What loads as expected:

- `http://example.com`: home page
- `http://example.com/api1.php/foo/bar`: some JSON data

What doesn't load:

- `http://1.app.example.com/foo/bar`:

  > 404 | Not Found | sfError404Exception
  >
  > Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/" (/).
  >
  > […]

*What am I missing?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by changing:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api1_dev.php [QSA,L]
```

into:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api1_dev.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Makes sense. I only wonder why in the `.htaccess` for `example.com`, the `$1`
is not necessary:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In ~ec2-user/project/web/.htaccess,

Uncomment RewriteBase /, it becomes this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

RewriteEngine On

# uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
# getting no_script_name to work
RewriteBase /

# we skip all files with .something
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
#RewriteRule .* - [L]

# we check if the .html version is here (caching)
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# no, so we redirect to our front web controller
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Please note the `AllowOverride None` in the configuration for `1.app.example.com`: `.htaccess` is not interpreted, and so changing it has no effect.